# Downloading &Extracting .gz

Tags: php

I am trying to download, and extract a .gz file. However, my logic seems to be right, and no errors are produced. However, the file does not appear on the server (neither does the .gz).

I have tried splitting it up into sections and running the code, but it's not even getting the .gz from the first step.

An idea what is wrong with my code?

```
<?php
$key = $_GET['key'];

$your_key = '0010111018474';


if ($key == $your_key)
{
    echo 'Your key '. $your_key . ' has been matched with the system key '. $key . '<br>';

    $url = "https://odds.smarkets.com/oddsfeed.xml.gz?event_type=horse_racing_race";
    $zipFile = "smarketOdds.gz"; // Local Zip File Path
    $zipResource = fopen($zipFile, "w");
    // Get The Zip File From Server
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $zipResource);
    $page = curl_exec($ch);
    if(!$page) {
    echo "Error :- ".curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);


    echo "Odds have been downloaded from Smarkets.<br>";


    //This input should be from somewhere else, hard-coded in this example

    // Raising this value may increase performance
    $buffer_size = 4096; // read 4kb at a time
    $out_file_name = str_replace('.gz', '.xml', $zipFile); 

    // Open our files (in binary mode)
    $file = gzopen($zipFile, 'rb');
    $out_file = fopen($out_file_name, 'wb'); 

    // Keep repeating until the end of the input file
    while (!gzeof($file)) {
        // Read buffer-size bytes
        // Both fwrite and gzread and binary-safe
        fwrite($out_file, gzread($file, $buffer_size));
    }

    // Files are done, close files
    fclose($out_file);
    gzclose($file);
    echo "Smarkets XML file has been extracted to server.";
}
else 
{
    echo "invalid key.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you sure the `fopen` of the `$zipResource` doesn't fails? permission issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried and it works:

```
<?php
$url = "https://odds.smarkets.com/oddsfeed.xml.gz?event_type=horse_racing_race";
$zipFile = "smarketOdds.gz"; // Local Zip File Path
$zipResource = fopen($zipFile, "w");
// Get The Zip File From Server
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $zipResource);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
fclose($zipResource);
if($page) {
    echo "file size: " . filesize($zipFile);
}
```

Output:

```
file size: 55458
```

Possible problems:

1. you failed to create your `smarketOdds.gz`, check that you haven correct permission, or just use "/tmp/smarketOdds.gz"
2. you got a timeout (after 10 seconds)?